# Как получить текущий год в js?

Tags: javascript

Есть код

```js
 document.write((new Date()).getFullYear())
```

ГуглХром и Lighthouse рекомендуют убрать этот код из-за `document.write`
Каким образом при помощи JS можно получить текущий год?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133052/discussion-on-question-by-arcadiy------js).

Answer (score 1):

Сам нашел пример, может кому и пригодится.

```js
document.getElementById('Year').appendChild(document.createTextNode(new Date().getFullYear()))
```

```html
<div>
    <span id="Year">      
    </span>
</div>
```